# Combining comparsion operators with other conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns `PERMNO`, `year`, `DIVAMT` indicating the firm (identifying number), the year and the amount of dividend paid in that year respectively.

I would like to add a further column that counts the number of years a firm paid dividends without cutting the dividend amount. The count of this variable should therefore go up, if the value of the current dividend (in year *t*) was either equal or bigger than the dividend in the preceeding year (year *t-1*). If the dividend is cut (dividend in year *t* < dividend in year *t-1*), the value should be reset to 0. Moreover, if the firm changes (different `PERMNO` number), the value should be reset as well.

For this matter, I wrote the following code:

```
div = (df["DIVAMT"])
div_lt = div.lt(div.shift()).cumsum()
df["no_cut"] = div.groupby([df["PERMNO"], div_lt ]).cumcount()
```

This code actually works as intended with regard to the aformentioned rule. I now would like to add a further condition to this rule stating that the counter should only be increased if the dividend amount is > 0. To further clearify my goal, I attached a sample with the current and desired output:

```
PERMNO  year    DIVAMT  no_cut desired
0   10000   1986    0.0000  0    0 
1   10005   1986    0.0000  0    0
2   10005   1987    0.0000  1    0
3   10005   1988    0.0000  2    0
4   10005   1989    0.0000  3    0
5   10005   1990    0.0000  4    0
6   10006   1951    0.0000  0    0
7   10006   1952    0.0000  1    0
8   10006   1953    0.0000  2    0
9   10006   1954    0.0000  3    0
10  10006   1955    2.0000  4    1
11  10006   1956    4.0000  5    2
12  10006   1957    3.6250  0    0
13  10006   1958    2.5000  0    0
14  10006   1959    2.5000  1    1
15  10006   1960    2.5000  2    2
16  10006   1961    2.5000  3    3
17  10006   1962    2.5750  4    4
18  10006   1963    2.0000  0    0
19  10006   1964    2.6250  1    1
20  10006   1965    2.2000  0    0
21  10006   1966    2.2000  1    1
22  10006   1967    2.2000  2    2
23  10006   1968    2.3500  3    3
24  10006   1969    4.8000  4    4
25  10006   1970    2.4000  0    0
26  10006   1971    2.4000  1    1
27  10006   1972    2.4000  2    2
28  10006   1973    2.4000  3    3
29  10006   1974    2.6000  4    4
30  10006   1975    2.6000  5    5
31  10006   1976    1.8500  0    0
32  10006   1977    2.0250  1    1
33  10006   1978    2.1350  2    2
34  10006   1979    2.3050  3    3
35  10006   1980    2.5650  4    4
36  10006   1981    2.7600  5    5
37  10006   1982    2.8000  6    6
38  10006   1983    2.9500  7    7
39  10007   1986    0.0000  0    0
40  10007   1989    0.0000  1    0
41  10008   1986    0.0000  0    0
42  10008   1987    0.0000  1    0
43  10010   1986    0.0000  0    0
44  10010   1987    0.0000  1    0
45  10010   1988    0.0000  2    0
46  10010   1989    0.0000  3    0    
47  10010   1990    0.0000  4    0
48  10010   1991    0.0000  5    0
49  10010   1992    0.0000  6    0
50  10010   1993    0.0000  7    0
51  10010   1994    0.0000  8    0
52  10011   1989    0.0000  0    0
53  10011   1990    0.0000  1    0
54  10011   1991    0.0000  2    0
55  10011   1992    0.0000  3    0
56  10011   1993    0.0000  4    0
57  10011   1994    0.0000  5    0
58  10011   1995    0.0000  6    0    
59  10011   1996    0.0000  7    0
60  10011   1997    0.0000  8    0
61  10012   1986    0.0000  0    0   
62  10012   1988    0.0000  1    0
63  10012   1989    0.0000  2    0
64  10012   1990    0.0000  3    0
65  10012   1991    0.0000  4    0
66  10012   1992    0.0000  5    0
67  10012   1993    0.0000  6    0
68  10012   1994    0.0000  7    0
69  10012   1995    0.0000  8    0
70  10012   1996    0.0000  9    0
71  10012   1997    0.0000  10   0
72  10012   1998    0.0000  11   0
73  10012   1999    0.0000  12   0
74  10012   2000    0.0000  13   0
75  10012   2001    0.0000  14   0
76  10012   2002    0.0000  15   0
77  10012   2003    0.0000  16   0
78  10012   2004    0.0000  17   0
79  10012   2005    0.0000  18   0
80  10013   1986    0.0000  0    0
```

As you can see, my code works as long as there is a dividend paid. If the dividend amount is zero, the variable does not yet take on the desired values, as the counter does increase as well. Does anybody know, how I can extend my code so it only if the dividend amount is > 0?

---

EDIT:
My Solution:

```
m1 = pd.DataFrame(df["DIVAMT"])
m1["DIVAMT_shift"] = m1["DIVAMT"].shift()
cond = [(m1["DIVAMT"] >= m1["DIVAMT_shift"]) & (m1["DIVAMT"] > 0)]
val = [False]
m1["g1_bool"] = np.select(cond, val, True)
m1["g1"] = m1["g1_bool"].cumsum()
dividend_year["no_cut"] = m1["DIVAMT"].groupby([df["PERMNO"], m1["g1"]]).cumcount()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. The result is in the column `'achieved'` that should be compared to yours `'desired'`

```
df1 = (df.groupby('PERMNO', as_index=False)
   .apply(
       lambda g: g.assign(v=((g['DIVAMT'].diff()>=0) & (g['DIVAMT']>0)))
    )
)
df1['achieved']  = df1.groupby(['PERMNO', (df1['v'].shift() & (~df1['v'])).cumsum()], as_index = False )['v'].cumsum()
df1.drop(columns = 'v').reset_index(drop = True)
```

output:

```
    PERMNO  year  DIVAMT  no_cut  desired  achieved
0    10000  1986   0.000       0        0         0
1    10005  1986   0.000       0        0         0
2    10005  1987   0.000       1        0         0
3    10005  1988   0.000       2        0         0
4    10005  1989   0.000       3        0         0
5    10005  1990   0.000       4        0         0
6    10006  1951   0.000       0        0         0
7    10006  1952   0.000       1        0         0
8    10006  1953   0.000       2        0         0
9    10006  1954   0.000       3        0         0
10   10006  1955   2.000       4        1         1
11   10006  1956   4.000       5        2         2
12   10006  1957   3.625       0        0         0
13   10006  1958   2.500       0        0         0
14   10006  1959   2.500       1        1         1
15   10006  1960   2.500       2        2         2
16   10006  1961   2.500       3        3         3
17   10006  1962   2.575       4        4         4
18   10006  1963   2.000       0        0         0
19   10006  1964   2.625       1        1         1
20   10006  1965   2.200       0        0         0
21   10006  1966   2.200       1        1         1
22   10006  1967   2.200       2        2         2
23   10006  1968   2.350       3        3         3
24   10006  1969   4.800       4        4         4
25   10006  1970   2.400       0        0         0
26   10006  1971   2.400       1        1         1
27   10006  1972   2.400       2        2         2
28   10006  1973   2.400       3        3         3
29   10006  1974   2.600       4        4         4
30   10006  1975   2.600       5        5         5
31   10006  1976   1.850       0        0         0
32   10006  1977   2.025       1        1         1
33   10006  1978   2.135       2        2         2
34   10006  1979   2.305       3        3         3
35   10006  1980   2.565       4        4         4
36   10006  1981   2.760       5        5         5
37   10006  1982   2.800       6        6         6
38   10006  1983   2.950       7        7         7
39   10007  1986   0.000       0        0         0
40   10007  1989   0.000       1        0         0
41   10008  1986   0.000       0        0         0
42   10008  1987   0.000       1        0         0
43   10010  1986   0.000       0        0         0
44   10010  1987   0.000       1        0         0
45   10010  1988   0.000       2        0         0
46   10010  1989   0.000       3        0         0
47   10010  1990   0.000       4        0         0
48   10010  1991   0.000       5        0         0
49   10010  1992   0.000       6        0         0
50   10010  1993   0.000       7        0         0
51   10010  1994   0.000       8        0         0
52   10011  1989   0.000       0        0         0
53   10011  1990   0.000       1        0         0
54   10011  1991   0.000       2        0         0
55   10011  1992   0.000       3        0         0
56   10011  1993   0.000       4        0         0
57   10011  1994   0.000       5        0         0
58   10011  1995   0.000       6        0         0
59   10011  1996   0.000       7        0         0
60   10011  1997   0.000       8        0         0
61   10012  1986   0.000       0        0         0
62   10012  1988   0.000       1        0         0
63   10012  1989   0.000       2        0         0
64   10012  1990   0.000       3        0         0
65   10012  1991   0.000       4        0         0
66   10012  1992   0.000       5        0         0
67   10012  1993   0.000       6        0         0
68   10012  1994   0.000       7        0         0
69   10012  1995   0.000       8        0         0
70   10012  1996   0.000       9        0         0
71   10012  1997   0.000      10        0         0
72   10012  1998   0.000      11        0         0
73   10012  1999   0.000      12        0         0
74   10012  2000   0.000      13        0         0
75   10012  2001   0.000      14        0         0
76   10012  2002   0.000      15        0         0
77   10012  2003   0.000      16        0         0
78   10012  2004   0.000      17        0         0
79   10012  2005   0.000      18        0         0
80   10013  1986   0.000       0        0         0
```